# How do I remove the original desktop environment after having installed a different one?

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, xfce

I installed Lubuntu a few days ago, wanting something nice and lightweight, but it didn't quite jive with me, so I installed xfce instead.

How do I remove the original desktop environment and all its components so they don't take up space on the computer?

I've seen a bunch of suggestions on here already, but they were all

1. For the LXDE version of Lubuntu, this is LXQT
2. For removing LXDE after it being the secondary desktop environment, rather than the built-in one.

Comment: Since it's been only a few days since you installed Lubuntu, I suggest just doing a fresh install of Xubuntu. Removing a DE completely is somewhat painful.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would do that but I've already set this up as my full working dev environment with all the network settings and proxies and the like. Having to back everything up just to reinstall the OS and put back everything is a bigger hassle

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

Start in text-only mode

```
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.
Select the line which starts with Advanced options.
Select the line ending with (recovery mode)
Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.
The PC will start in a terminal.
```

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
 mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
 apt-get update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
 apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of lxqt that are not necessary in xfce

```
 aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lxqt),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall xubuntu-desktop

```
 apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
 deborphan
 apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
 deborphan --libdevel
 apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
 deborphan --find-config
 dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
 apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
 apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
 reboot
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why I need to boot into text only mode and then mount my partitions in rw mode

Comment: Electric Coffee, this method is removing libraries from the graphical interface. Some may be used by your xubuntu desktop. That is why in a later step, you restore your current desktop environment with `apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop`. This will pull part of these libraries back in, but this time only those effectively needed for the xubuntu desktop.

Comment: Next time you plan to test another desktop, you may want to record all packages that are going to be installed in a text file. That way, you will be able to granularly remove them again.